# "Getting SSLError while trying to 'get' content using 'requests' from a 'HTTPS' url"

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, https

I am trying to call a HTTPS url using `requests.get()`. But getting `SSLError`.

It is on my local machine.
Python version is 3.7. I am using VS Code.
If I try to pass `verify=False` to `request.get()` call succeeds with a warning.

Here is the line of code:

```py
resp = requests.get('https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/primary-images/irisflowersclassicpurple.jpg')
```

Why am I getting SSL error? How to fix it?
Please someone explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like an untrusted SSL certificate

Have you tried setting `verify=True` ?

That will force the certificate to be validated against the library's own trusted certificate authorities (CA)